# How i can download only html/text with wget, and without images, css etc

Tags: python, parsing, wget

For research and training, I decided to use the wget function to increase the speed of parsing any pages. Before that, I used BeautifulSoup, BeautifulSoup('lxml'), pure lxml, selectolax.parser, with urllib and requests, and all these steps made it possible to speed up the data retrieval speed of the parser, but I came to an even faster way of parsing large data, this is WGET, but the problem is because I'm downloading a page with all the content, it's completely standalone, and I want to download only html, because 100,000 pages took 21 GB, it's very expensive for storage, and generally not necessary to get counter data from elements, here's the code:

```
import os
os.system(f'wget -P C:/test -i C:/test/urls.txt')
```

how can i filter only html text or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To detect type of resource, without download it, one might use [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/methods/head) verb. GNU `wget` has `--spider` option which does this, though if you elect to use it you would then need to parse its' output to get type.
I would use [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) to do detection, then filter `urls.txt`, then use wget to download selected. I propose following function to detect type for given URL:

```
import urllib.request
def detect_content_type(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url,method='HEAD')
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    return r.headers.get_content_type()
```

usage example

```
print(detect_content_type("http://www.example.com")) # text/html
```

having such function you should be able to write code which use it against each entry in `urls.txt` and append it to another file if it is `text/html`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I tried your code, but in general all my links in urls.txt are downloaded as name.html in one file without additional additions, and of course pass your check, if I understood everything correctly, it checks or I will download html from the link. But I was trying to move in the direction of the fact that this one element.html which I downloaded via wget has ~250kb and it firstly takes time to download, secondly it takes a lot of memory,

Comment: ...I was thinking if it is possible to somehow download an html file but without css, without pictures on the offline page that I downloaded, because I won't need all of this for future parsing, I'm going to parse only text data. So I would save time for uploading an html file with a page, and accordingly memory for saving a set of html files. Maybe this is an unrealistic mission, maybe wget first downloads the entire file and then it will be possible to delete something from it, that's why I'm asking people who use this command like professionals.

Comment: im check file that i download, maybee its my browser when i open name.html file uploading all images when im scroling down? can its be true?